# Group by count once

Tags: sql-server, group-by

My data is like below:

```
ClassId ClassName   StudentId   Subject     SubjectId  
-----------------------------------------------------
1         ESL        12         English      20  
1         ESL        13         Science      30  
1         ESL        12         Social       40  
1         ESL        12         Maths        50
```

Required output: parameters are Subject column values

```
ClassId ClassName   TotalStudents   SubjectIds   
-----------------------------------------------    
1        ESL         2               20, 40, 50, 30
```

When one student takes multiple subjects then count student only once, so in the above data 12 is one student id takes multiple subjects so counted only once. TotalStudents value is 2 (1 from student id 12 and 1 from student id 13)

I am not looking for how to display subjectIds column value in comma separated string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this question about only counting each student once, or about getting subjects into comma delimited form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COUNT DISTINCT` then use [STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) for combined the subject

```
declare @temp table
(ClassId int,ClassName   nvarchar(max),StudentId   int,Subject nvarchar(max),    SubjectId  int)

insert into @temp values (1,'ESL',12,'English' ,     20 ) 
insert into @temp values (1,'ESL',13,'Science' ,     30 ) 
insert into @temp values (1,'ESL',12,'Social ' ,     40 ) 
insert into @temp values (1,'ESL',12,'Maths  ' ,     50 ) 

select ClassId,ClassName,COUNT(DISTINCT StudentId) CNT,
STUFF( (SELECT ',' + CAST(t1.SubjectId AS NVARCHAR) 
                             FROM @temp t1
                             WHERE StudentId = t1.StudentId
                             FOR XML PATH('')), 
                            1, 1, '') SubjectIdS
 from @temp 
GROUP BY ClassId,ClassName
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT can be applied inside aggregate functions.

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) FROM table_name;

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to display the `SubjectId`s, then you need to use a [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) clause to group the resultset by `ClassId` and `ClassName`.

```
SELECT ClassId, ClassName, COUNT(distinct StudentId) as TotalStudents
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ClassId, ClassName
```

See this example at <kbd>[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/951be/2)</kbd>